# Strong adjective endings

Tags: adjective-ending

I have encountered the following sentence in a German text:

*Die Sophienschule ist eine Stadtteilschule mit modernem pädagogischen Konzept.*

What is the rule behind the adjective endings in "modernem pädagogischen Konzept"? Why isn't it as "modernem pädagogische Konzept"?

Comment: I assume you meant *pädagogischem*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is just a quirk of the German language without any known explanation.

The strong ending in the dative singular masculine and neuter is **‑em**, the weak ending is *‑en*. Adjectives are expected to carry parallel endings, and they always do outside the dative singular masculine and neuter.

> mit modern**er** pädagogisch**er** Betreuung
> modern**e** pädagogisch**e** Konzepte

But in the dative singular masculine and neuter, adjectives following a strongly inflected adjective on **‑em** often show the weak ending *‑en*.

> mit modern**em** pädagogisch*en* Konzept

However, parallel inflection is always possible.

> mit modern**em** pädagogisch**em** Konzept

One can easily search for examples with [DWDS Korpora](https://www.dwds.de/r).

> Nein, sagt das Böse, es spricht mit tiefem britischen Akzent.
>
> Scheitert die Integration ausländischer Priester am Unwillen der deutschen Gläubigen, sich auch mal eine Predigt mit hartem indischem Akzent anzuhören?
>
> (Amir spricht mit perfektem amerikanischem Akzent)
>
> In ihrer kleinen Küche erzählt Anna Kerbel bei starkem Tee und mit starkem russischem Akzent von ihren vielen russischen Freunden, vom Strand von Mallorca und von den Kollegen im Baumarkt.
>
> Er ist dreifacher Familienvater, spricht ein Englisch mit kräftigem italienischen Akzent.
>
> Mit deutlichem griechischem Akzent erzählt Ioannidis begeistert von seiner Forschung.
>
> Der Imam spricht Englisch mit starkem pakistanischen Akzent, in der kleinen Halle sitzen etwa vierzig Männer auf Gebetsteppichen, ein paar Frauen warten in der hinteren linken Ecke des Raumes.
>
> Mit dickem amerikanischen Akzent, aber voller Inbrunst.
>
> Auch sein Team vermittelte einen gelassenen Eindruck: vor dem Konzert blödeln Fan-Artikel Verkäufer mit starkem englischen Akzent mit potenziellen Käufern herum, scherzen und lachen - keine Spur von kommerziellem Massenbetrieb.

Comment: Having more than one strong adjective with a noun is relatively rare. It almost never occurs in spoken language, because usually an article is used. I think it is this rarity why German grammar is somewhat fuzzy here.

Comment: @RHa It's not that rare. There's prenominal genitives, determiners without endings and other contexts where no determiner is needed: *von Jack Dorseys neuem sozialem Netzwerk, mit dessen nervösem kleinem Hund, ein weiterer fataler Schritt, mit neuem optischem Auftritt, süße kleine Maus!, als erstem deutschem Verein.* Also the supposed rarity wouldn't explain why the phenomenon is limited to the dative singular masculine and neuter.

Comment: "Mit moderne*m* pädagogische*m* Konzept" - da ist das Konzept sowohl modern wie auch pädagogisch. "mit moderne*m* pädagogische*n* Konzept" - da ist das "pädagogische Konzept" modern. Mit anderen Worten: einmal bezieht sich das "modern" auf das "Konzept" selbst, ein anderes Mal auf das "pädagogisch".

Comment: @bakunin Solche Behauptungen liest man immer wieder, sie lassen sich aber nicht durch Daten bestätigen.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Ich weiß nicht, was Du mit "Daten" meinst. Mein Sprachgefühl sagt mir, was ich vorhin geschrieben habe oder, anders ausgedrückt: ich würde es so verstehen (und bin damit vermutlich nicht alleine). Repräsentative Umfrage oder Doppeltblindstudie zu dem Thema habe ich allerdings keine veranstaltet.

Comment: Würde *modern* sich auf *pädagogisch* beziehen, müsste es heißen *Mit modern pädagogischem Konzept*.